# Windows 10 laptop\external keyboard malfunction (tab, I, spacebar, dash, backspace, enter works)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm running Windows 10 fully updated. My laptop keyboard & also an external keyboard now only lets me use tab, I, spacebar, dash, backspace and enter.

Pressing WinKey+spacebar continuously to select an alternative keyboard does not help.

Has anyone ever heard of this? Any idea how I can get it working again and into my machine?

Comment: does the on screen keyboard (right click taskbar>Show touch keyboard button)  work ??

Comment: On the login screen click "ease of access" on bottom right corner(next to the power button) then choose on screen keyboard from the list

Comment: The screen only keyboard allowed me eventually to login, thanks Elmo. I turned off user login. I have removed the external keyboard and readded and updated some drivers from the Lenovo site - my machine is a Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro laptop. The keyboard was working for 10 minutes at a time but for the last day has totally stopped working. Any ideas are much appreciated as I have no machine :-(

Comment: "totally stopped working" - tab, I, spacebar, dash and enter still working ?? Are you using win 10 v1903 ..??? did this start after updating to v1903 ??

Comment: go to Device manager> Keyboards> Standard PS/2 Keyboard> Uninstall Device and restart your laptop...dont install any lenovo drivers and check.

Comment: Elmo, I was not able to reply last night as I can't use the keyboard :-( I had done that before and I tried again and restarted the machine to no avail. The last time the keyboard worked I installed the new Lenovo System Update, system_update_5.07.0084.exe, and updated all. This is bizarre and absolutely killing me with my home machine unusable.

Comment: OK..well boot into safe mode and try....also try booting from a bootable USB(Linux ubuntu or anything) and then check...if its a windows issue then I guess you could reset your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Anker data hub (AK-A7515211) connected to my laptop, which had HP keyboard (KU-0316), Anker AK-UBA 2.4G Wireless Vertical Ergonomic Optical Mouse (AK-98ANWVM-UBA), Anker USB 3.0 Portable Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (AK-A7610011) connected to it.

I brought my work machine home and plugged in the datahub and believe it or not on my work laptop keyboard *only* tab, I, spacebar, dash, backspace and enter worked!

I experimented with the peripherals and when I plug the ethernet adaptor straight into the laptop rather than the datahub with the datahub (and other peripherals to it) connected my keyboards stay working!

So it looks like a datahub driver failure? But problem diagnosed and keyboard back! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**If you're seeing the described symptoms on Windows login screen, start by making sure that your `CTRL` key isn't physically stuck.**

Adding this answer here, because this question comes up pretty often on search engines when troubleshooting a particular issue that I believe was also related to the original question (though perhaps through driver issues?), because the symptoms are so similar.

This is exactly how the Windows password prompt behaves when the `CTRL` key is stuck.

`CTRL+i` will insert a `TAB` character, which will show up as a censored keystroke, leading the user to believe that `i` works while most other keys don't. `CTRL+-` will input a special character that applications typically interpret to mean "Zoom out", but in the case of the password prompt, it will just be interpreted as part of the password.

`TAB`, `SPACE`, `ENTER` and `BACKSPACE` can work normally while holding `CTRL`.